# How to have a custom URI path for specific page template

Tags: htaccess, child-pages, paths

I have a custom template file called page_system.php. I have a page in Wordpress called "System" which uses this template. The path to view this page is:

```
www.mysite.com/system/
```

I want a way via htacess or otherwise, that would allow me to add anything after the path and put it in a get variable, so that I can use the variable as I see fit. I want it to ignore the built in Wordpress paths after the last '/'.

So, for example,

```
www.mysite.com/system/variable1/variable2
```

would look the same in the URL bar, but it would actually show

```
www.mysite.com/system/?getvariables=variable1/variable2
```

My attempts at editing the .htaccess file so far haven't worked. My most recent failed attempt is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^\/system\/(.*)$ system/?getvariables=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

If anybody could help I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a rewrite rule to WordPress. There are several options to do it depending on your exact needs.

Maybe the most general is using [`add_rewrite_tag()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_tag/) and [`add_rewrite_rule()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/):

```
add_action( 'init', 'cyb_rewrite_rules' );
function cyb_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_tag( '%variable1%', '([^&]+)' );
    add_rewrite_tag( '%variable2%', '([^&]+)' );
    add_rewrite_rule( ^system/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&variable1=$matches[2]&variable2=$matches[3]', 'top' );
}
```

Now, if the URL match the regext "system/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/", for example this one:

```
https://example.com/system/value1/value2
```

The page "system" will be queried by WordPress and you will be able to get the extra values using [`get_query_var()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var):

```
$variable1 = get_query_var( 'variable1' );
$variable2 = get_query_var( 'variable2' );
```

Both functions, `add_rewrite_tag()` and `add_rewrite_rule()`, are wrappers of [`WP_Rewrite`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rewrite/) methods.

Note: after a new rewrite rule is added to WordPress, the set of rules need to be flushed and rebuild. This can be done with `flush_rewrite_rules()` function. This function makes a database operation that it's needed only once, that is why it is commonly used in plugin activation/deactivation hooks:

```
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'flush_rewrite_rules' );
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'cyb_activation_hook' );
function cyb_activation_hook() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

Rewrite rules can be flushed also in "Settings -> Permalinks"; just click "Save" button and rewrite are rebuilt.